# How to configure plugin properties in gradle

Tags: gradle, syntax, configuration

Among other stuff I have the following in my gradle build file

```
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.6'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

In my limited understanding of gradle all 4 pieces are configurations for a plugin. Yet they look very different.

Apart from the different syntax, what is the semantic difference between the 4 variations?

And how am I supposed to understand from the documentation which style to use?

Answer (score 2):

```
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
```

This is [Java Plugin Convention Property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N12392), i.e. properties that allows you to set their values with project properties instead of only task properties. These properties are usually listed in the plugin documentation. You can read more about convention properties [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.dsl.ConventionProperty.html).

---

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '6.6'
}
```

The type of this task is CheckstyleExtension and you can find its available properties in the its [DSL Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.html).

---

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

Here you define an instance of task of type Wrapper. As such, task `wrapper` has the same properties as the Wrapper task type which its DSL is defined [here](https://docs.gradle.org/1.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html).

---

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

This syntax is used for configuring all tasks of a specific type. In this case you're picking all tasks of type [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) and configure their [options.encoding](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:encoding) property.

Comment: Ok, the Convention Property thing helps, I can configure those on the root of the script and the get special mentioning in the documentation. But the other 3 variants are all documented as properties. How should I know how to use them?

Comment: You should be able to find the documentation about these task types in [Gradle DSL Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/) so just look into the task DSL and find the relevant properties and their usage. Note that in many cases the DSL also contains some examples about the common properties used to customize the task.